# How to use Glide to transform the images loaded on an ImageView that came from the Gallery or sdcard?

Tags: android, android-glide

So I have learned how to use glide to load images from a server and transform them and it works nicely.

But now, I want to know how I can use the same transformations on an image I have set to the ImageView before I set it as src?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it in same way as for images from the server `Glide.with(context).load(uri).transform(new Transform()).into(view)` where uri is your local uri of the picture, and Transform is a class of your transformation.